# Search text contains some characters

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to modify my codes where it will show my data tables when searching only some characters contains within the entire table. For instance, if the word "vegetables" appears in one of the columns, it should display all columns that contain that term. However, if you merely type, say, "veg," the data will be displayed.

```
/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var concat = formObject.searchtext.toString().toLowerCase();  
  var result = "";  
if(concat){ //Execute if form passes search text      
  result = search(concat);  
}  
  return result;
}
//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS ;

function search(searchtext){  
var spreadsheetId   = '1xNda3fiwCjehclosCZNyH5Y4v-vkZ4UHiyLwOnZWZ5Q';
var sheetName = "App";  
var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();  
var data = range.getValues();  
var ar = [];   
  
data.forEach(function(f) {    
  
  if (~[f[5]].indexOf(searchtext)) {
ar.push([ f[0],f[1],f[2],f[3],f[4] ])
}
});
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `For example, one of the columns has a word “vegetables” it should show columns which has the same word but by just typing let's say “veg” only it will show up the data.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected value?

Comment: For instance, if the word "vegetables" appears in one of the columns, it should display all columns that contain that term. However, if you merely type, say, "veg," the data will be displayed. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Appreciate the assistance. What I really want is to have a powerful search options. By typing just some of the character in the search field, I should be able to get the result instead of putting the whole word. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `What I really want is to have a powerful search options. By typing just some of the character in the search field, I should be able to get the result instead of putting the whole word.`, I understand it. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected value. So, I cannot still post an answer. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this, again.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible with plain HTML and JS.

(In the JS the 'array' variable would be the array of items to search)

```js
var array = ["vegtable", "fruit", "chocolate"];
 
displayList();
 
 
function autoSearch(){
    var search=document.getElementById('search').value.toLowerCase();
    var parent=document.getElementById("result");
    var children=parent.getElementsByTagName('tr');
 
    for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
        var keyword=children[i].innerText;
        if(keyword.toLowerCase().indexOf(search)>-1){
            children[i].style.display="";
        }else{
            children[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
 
}
 
 
function displayList(){
    array.sort(function(a,b){
        if(a < b){
            return -1;
        }
 
        if(a > b){
            return 1;
        }
 
        return 0;
    });
 
    data = "";
 
    for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        data += "<tr><td>"+array[i]+"</td></tr>";
    }
 
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = data;
}
```

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter a name</label>
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search here..." onkeyup="autoSearch()">
    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <thead class="info">
            <tr>
                <th>Result</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="result"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Appreciate it man. I'm afraid I don't know how to add these to my existing codes.